# Is there an efficient way to load textures as .PNG images for a simple 2D game

Tags: java, file, textures

I am writing a simple 2D block based game (similar to Minecraft) to get started with Java. I have a lot of game mechanics like world generation working, but loading textures is bulky and inefficient. Basically I have all textures loaded individually with a load function (textures are 16x16 .PNG files). Each block in the game has a name (eg. "stone", "dirt"), and when the game renders the tile, it loads the texture from the textureManager class. This works but I have to hardcode each texture loading and returning. What I want to do is make the textures load automatically but still have their string indexes. For example I want the game to load all .PNG files in the textures folder but preserve their name so I can say something like loadTexture("stone").

Here is my current texture manager code. It simple loads each file when the game starts and darkens each for the background tiles. This is a pain to add new textures and is just not efficient.

```
package graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RescaleOp;

public class textureManager {
    private static final BufferedImage darken(BufferedImage image) {
        return new RescaleOp(.7f, 0, null).filter(image, null);
    }

    private static final String path = "/assets/textures/";
    // textures 
    public static final BufferedImage unknown   = renderer.loadImage(path + "unknown.png");
    private static final BufferedImage stone    = renderer.loadImage(path + "stone.png");
    private static final BufferedImage grass    = renderer.loadImage(path + "grass.png");
    private static final BufferedImage dirt     = renderer.loadImage(path + "dirt.png");
    private static final BufferedImage iron_ore = renderer.loadImage(path + "iron_ore.png");
    private static final BufferedImage coal_ore = renderer.loadImage(path + "coal_ore.png");
    private static final BufferedImage diamond_ore = renderer.loadImage(path + "diamond_ore.png");
    private static final BufferedImage bedrock  = renderer.loadImage(path + "bedrock.png");
    private static final BufferedImage andesite = renderer.loadImage(path + "andesite.png");
    private static final BufferedImage granite  = renderer.loadImage(path + "granite.png");
    private static final BufferedImage marble   = renderer.loadImage(path + "marble.png");

    // darkened textures
    private static final BufferedImage dark_stone = darken(stone);
    private static final BufferedImage dark_grass = darken(grass);
    private static final BufferedImage dark_dirt = darken(dirt);
    private static final BufferedImage dark_iron_ore = darken(iron_ore);
    private static final BufferedImage dark_coal_ore = darken(coal_ore);
    private static final BufferedImage dark_diamond_ore = darken(diamond_ore);
    private static final BufferedImage dark_andesite = darken(andesite);
    private static final BufferedImage dark_granite = darken(granite);
    private static final BufferedImage dark_marble = darken(marble);

    // animations
    private static Animation player   = new Animation("player");
    private static Animation lava     = new Animation("lava");
    private static Animation plant_01 = new Animation("plant_01");

    /** returns the textures of the name provided */
    public static BufferedImage getTexture(String name, boolean darken) {
        if(name.equals("air")) return null;
        if(name.equals("stone"))    if(!darken) return stone;           else return dark_stone;
        if(name.equals("grass"))    if(!darken) return grass;           else return dark_grass;
        if(name.equals("dirt"))     if(!darken) return dirt;            else return dark_dirt;
        if(name.equals("iron_ore")) if(!darken) return iron_ore;        else return dark_iron_ore;
        if(name.equals("coal_ore")) if(!darken) return coal_ore;        else return dark_coal_ore;
        if(name.equals("diamond_ore")) if(!darken) return diamond_ore;  else return dark_diamond_ore;
        if(name.equals("bedrock"))  return bedrock;
        if(name.equals("andesite")) if(!darken) return andesite;        else return dark_andesite;
        if(name.equals("granite"))  if(!darken) return granite;         else return dark_granite;
        if(name.equals("marble"))   if(!darken) return marble;          else return dark_marble;

        return unknown;
    }

    /** returns the animation of the name provided */
    public static Animation getAnimation(String name) {
        if(name.equals("player"))   return player;
        if(name.equals("lava"))     return lava;
        if(name.equals("plant_01")) return plant_01;

        return null;
    }
}
```

While this code works I would like to add a more efficient way but I do not know how. I was thinking of using an array list to store the images, but then it would not accept a string index. Perhaps a custom class that could manage an array list and a name index?

note: the animations are a custom class that animates the textures that loads from a folder. those can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The way i would do it is instead of listing all the files you want to load. load all the files in that path. put them into a map `Map<String, BufferedImage> textures = new HashMap<>();`  then you create the key from the file name. you can then generate and add the dark textures, adding 'dark_' or 'd' to the `Key`. then in get texture all you need to do is `if (darken) textures.get('d'+name) else textures.get(name)`
once all the textures are loaded from files here is something to get the dark versions

```
textures.putAll(textures.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry->"d"+entry.getKey(),entry->darken(entry.getValue()))));
```

Comment: I am currently working on loading the files into the hash map. I will combine the code from your response and the other one before and make a texture loading function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html).

A common (probably the most common) implementation of Map is [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html):

```
private static final Map<String, Map<Boolean, BufferedImage>> textures;

static {
    String[] baseNames = {
        "unknown",
        "stone",
        "grass",
        "dirt",
        "iron_ore",
        "coal_ore",
        "diamond_ore",
        "bedrock",
        "andesite",
        "granite",
        "marble",
    };

    Map<String, Map<Boolean, BufferedImage>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String baseName : baseNames) {
        BufferedImage regular =
            renderer.loadImage(path + baseName + ".png");
        BufferedImage dark = darken(regular);

        Map<Boolean, BufferedImage> regularAndDark = new HashMap<>(2);
        regularAndDark.put(false, regular);
        regularAndDark.put(true, dark);

        map.put(baseName, Collections.unmodifiableMap(regularAndDark));
    }

    textures = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}

/** returns the textures of the name provided */
public static BufferedImage getTexture(String name, boolean darken) {
    Map<Boolean, BufferedImage>> matches = textures.get(name);
    assert matches != null : "No textures for name \"" + name + "\"";
    return matches.get(darken);
}
```

However… there is room for improvement:

- As you can see, I added an `assert` statement to make sure no invalid string arguments are provided.  This can be avoided by using an `enum` value as an image key instead of a String, removing the possibility of misspellings.
- `Map<Boolean, BufferedImage>>` is a little hard to follow.  I would make a simple inner class to hold both, so the structure is more obvious.

With that in mind, it looks like this:

```
public enum TextureType {
    UNKNOWN,
    STONE,
    GRASS,
    DIRT,
    IRON_ORE,
    COAL_ORE,
    DIAMOND_ORE,
    BEDROCK,
    ANDESITE,
    GRANITE,
    MARBLE,
}

private static class Textures {
    final BufferedImage regular;
    final BufferedImage dark;

    Textures(BufferedImage regular) {
        this.regular = Objects.requireNonNull(regular,
            "Image cannot be null");
        this.dark = darken(regular);
    }
}

private static final Map<TextureType, Textures> textures;

static {
    Map<TextureType, Textures> map = new EnumMap(TextureType.class);
    for (TextureType type : TextureType.values()) {
        map.put(type,
            new Textures(renderer.loadImage(path + baseName + ".png")));
    }

    textures = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}

/** returns the textures of the name provided */
public static BufferedImage getTexture(TextureType type, boolean darken) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(type, "Texture type cannot be null");
    Textures match = textures.get(type);
    return darken ? match.dark : match.regular;
}
```

Comment: Your second example works well. I got the enum list to load when the textures are being rendered. The only problem is that the enum crashes the game if a block is not found instead of returning an unknown value (just a blank texture). I had some code to check if a value was valid, but because the rendered has to call the getTexture function approximately 2400 times per frame, the check reduced the frame rate too much to be playable.

Comment: What does “a block is not found” mean?  Are you saying the texture type can be null?  If it’s not null, then by definition, it must be one of the enum constants and there must be a corresponding image for it.